# WebGl rotation matrix

Tags: webgl

I have this very simple rotation program in Webgl to get some understanding of rotation matrix.
http://poly.byethost18.com/pyra1.htm

As you can see the object doesn't turn around actually.
The code for the vertex shader is here:

```
float angle = radians( theta );
float c = cos( angle );
float s = sin( angle );
mat4 ry = mat4( c, 0.0, -s, 0.0,
                0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0,
                s, 0.0,  c, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 );

gl_Position =  ry * vPosition;
```

I guess it's a kinda regular beginners stuff but what could be the cause?

Comment: glad you found the solution. [Here's an article on matrices you might find useful](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html).

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add

`gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);`